# unable to install bower using npm on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

Have tried out out `npm install -g bower` but the iInstallation gets stuck in this phase:

[image: Screenshot of the terminal while installing node modules]

It shows no error message.

What causes this issue and how can it be solved?

Comment: Its just gets stuck. Shows no error

Comment: To use Bower on Windows, you must install Git for Windows correctly. Be sure to check the git installation

Comment: git ,python ,pip all have been installed correctly

Comment: I installed it using powershell running as administrator, worked fine. I'm also a Windows Insider so I have a 'non stable Windows 10 build'

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the node.js package. It will fix the issue. 
The problem is/was with the cmd permissions to the files and directories in

```
AppData
```

folder.